# Can't get out the receive file loop in send file using socket java

Tags: java, sockets

I am developing client-server app. From client, I send a file to server. 
Here is my code about read file at server:

```
    private void readfile() throws Exception{
            String filename="data.xml";
    FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream(filename);
    BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(fos);
    BufferedReader buff_read = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(input,"UTF-8"));
    byte[] buffer=new byte[1024];
    String line;
    int count;
    while((count=input.read(buffer))>0){
        fos.write(buffer,0,count);
        fos.flush();
    }
    System.out.println("het");
    fos.close();
}
```

But I can't get out of the while loop. String "het" nerver show in console screen while I can read file data.xml by notepad++ mean that the file sent success.
Can you help me solve this problem.
Sorry for my poor Englisg.

Comment: You are throwing Exception which mean even Runtime Exceptions will be thrown. Are you sure no exception is occurring? Try printing the bytes read(count) in each loop before flushing.

Comment: The flush() inside the loop is counterproductive. You're preventing the BufferedOutputStream from doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `input`in your code is the input stream from the socket.

You do not tell us how you send the file to your socket, and this is important, but I am guessing that you have something similar on the 'client' side, where you read a file, and use a `byte[]` buffer to send the data over the client's OutputStream.

I am also guessing that you do not close the OutputStream on the client side.

When reading from a Socket InputStream the only time you will `read(...)` and get -1 is when the client side closes the OutputStream. I am assuming that the client does not do this, and thus your while loop is waiting for the InputStream to close.

So the problem is likely to be on the client side of the process, the code that sends the file. It has successfully sent the data, but it has not indicated to the server that the transmission is done, so the server is waiting.

If your system requires that you continue using the socket after the file is sent, then the client side cannot close the socket, and you will need to implement a protocol so that the server knows when the client side is done. For example, the client can start by sending 4 bytes (an integer) indicating the number of bytes in the file it is going to send, and then the server can interpret those bytes, and then read that number of bytes from the stream.

Answer (score 0):

The read() method returns -1 at end of stream, which for a socket means the peer has closed the connection. If you're not getting -1, the peer isn't closing the connection.

Comment: But I don't want to close socket Because I need send more file after.